# Use `VLOOKUP` to return previous column of search key (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a system that accepts working with `ARRAYFORMULA`, so I use `VLOOKUP`. Let's go to the example:

```
ABA   ZZZ
EBE   XXX
IBI   TTT
OBO   UUU
UBU   VVV
```

In that case if I wanted to look for `IBI` and return the next column, I would use`=VLOOKUP("IBI",A1:B,2,FALSE)` and it would return `TTT`.

Now, if so, if I wanted to search `TTT` to return the column before it, to get the value `IBI`, how should I proceed?

I tried using `-1` in the `index` of `VLOOKUP` and also tried using `INDIRECT("B1:A")` to invert the columns, but neither option worked.

If think it is best to help directly through the spreadsheet, here I leave the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PTmWDpD_xmI4WEIGuveduuTZGdyndc9aJd_GRPX8E4k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the best way, for a search of only one value, it can be used as follows:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("TTT",{B:B,A:A},2,FALSE)))`

If you are looking for multiple values placed on different lines, you can use with `ARRAY` quietly, just changing `"TTT"` for the desired value column, such as the `D` column, would be like this :

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1:D,{B:B,A:A},2,FALSE)))`

Answer (score 1):

> If I wanted to search TTT to return the column before it, to get the value IBI, how should I proceed?

I don't know about Google Sheets but with Excel you cant. Your data must be laid out in left to right and the index you are asking for is interpreted to be to the right. You cannot ask it to go left.

There are tricks and alternate formulas to do reverse, but a vanilla call to `VLOOKUP` is only left to right.

Alternatives for reverse direction: https://www.exceltip.com/lookup-formulas/reverse-vlookup-in-microsoft-excel.html

Comment: I just posted an answer with the form I found to solve the problem, I found it very simple and intuitive. Thanks so much for the initial tip.

Answer (score 1):

Adding headers to your data can be a quick fix and would allow you to go left or right.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$6,MATCH(E5,$B$1:$B$6,0),MATCH(D5,$A$1:$B$1,0))
=INDEX(Index('entire data set'), MATCH('TTT', column where 'TTT' is,0),match('Your data header along row 1')
```

[image: your data with headers]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=index(A:A, match("TTT", B:B), 1)
```

Match returns the row number, index searches for 1st column at the row number within 'A:A'.

Reference: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/left-lookup.html

Comment: This form unfortunately does not accept ```ARRAYFORMULA``` nor ```FILTER```

Comment: Could i ask how you were using ARRAYFORMULA()? I didn't have any issues using `=index(ARRAYFORMULA(A:A), match("TTT", ARRAYFORMULA(B:B), 1))`

Comment: If I want to fetch more than one value, in different rows, it only returns the result of the first row. Like for example: ```=ARRAYFORMULA(index(ARRAYFORMULA(A:A), match(D1:D, ARRAYFORMULA(B:B), 1)))```